# Animated movie with time travel and where people where enslaved in mines

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel, animated-series

I would like to identify animated movie from my childhood.

1. Not sure about language, animation style could be anime or similar.
2. Watched it on VHS in early 90's so it could be from 90's or 80's.
3. Teenagers or young adults in time traveling ship. They got to some dystopian/apocalyptic setting where people where enslaved in mines, one of them fell in love with native girl(princess?). They helped to free those people, fighting guards (robots or maybe monsters or armored soldiers).
4. At some point they lost their ship, or were very close to losing it.

Comment: Time travelling robots?

Comment: If the answer is indeed starchaser then starchaser is getting up there in duplicate identify this questions.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like "Starchaser:The Legend of Orin" (1985)

The movie contains no time travel, but it does contain robots forcing enslaved humans to work in mines, a hero in a starship, and the hero falling in love with a princess. It was released on VHS and Laserdisc on March 25, 1986 by Paramount Home Video according to Wikipedia.

Here is a trailer from YouTube: